# Magento grid, getting incorrect total value

Tags: magento

I created a grid. Issues is i am getting total number of records incorrectly. But all the records are in the grid. 
I tried in grid.html $this->getCollection()->getSize() code and it returns the incorrect value.

But count($this->getCollection()) returns the correct value. How can i solve this issues with $this->getCollection()->getSize().

Can anyone help me please.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the classic case of using a group by clause or a having clause (or both) on your collection. Magento's `getSelectCountSql` function does not account for the group by or the having clause because of its poor frontend performance. Instead it generally uses indeces and statistics. However, if you would like to you can override your collection's `getSelectCountSql` as follows:

```
public function getSelectCountSql($select) {
    $countSelect = clone $select;
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    if ($select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING)) {
        //No good way to chop this up, so just subquery it
        $subQuery = new Zend_Db_Expr("(".$countSelect->__toString().")");
        $countSelect
            ->reset()
            ->from(array('temp' => $subQuery))
            ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns('COUNT(*)')
        ;
    } else {
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        // Count doesn't work with group by columns keep the group by
        if (count($select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->distinct(true);
            $group = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
        } else {
            $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
        }
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```

This should return the correct number from `getSize`

Comment: Yes it did not work because of GROUP BY. I wrote the sql in another way to solve the issue.